# Django Initial value for date picker

Tags: django

Is there a way to set initial value for date picker? 
I would like to get today's date. 
My code:

```
class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'
    value = date.today()


class testerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tester
        fields = ('phandlowy', 'data_wypozyczenia')
        widgets = {'data_wypozyczenia': DateInput(),}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initial={} from the view works fine.

You can also redefine the field like

```py
class testerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tester
        fields = ('phandlowy', 'data_wypozyczenia')

    data_wypozyczenia = forms.DateField(
        initial=date.today(),
        required=True,
        input_formats=["%d/%m/%Y", "%Y-%m-%d"],
        widget=DateInput()
    )
```

And remove value assignment from DateInput class!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `initial={'data_wypozyczenia': date.today()}` when constructing the form instance (as in the view.)

For example:

```
form_instance = testerForm(initial={'data_wypozyczenia': date.today()})
```

Comment: Hi, it didn't helped unfortunately :(